# How to implement Business Rules

Tags: business-process-management, business-rules

i've been trying to figure out how to deal with Business Rules in the following format:

- a booking has 1 to n (n = 200) articles
- problem P shall be handled by the System XYZ
- a specifict data-class shall be supported in the System XYZ
- the communication to the customer shall be done by the organization Z.
- it is possible to change a specific value in an order
- the system XYZ shall be able to evaluate if a customer is able to pay monthly rates

in addition, many rules i got explain certain things that need to be fulfilled in order to let a future system work correctly. In my eyes, these rules are technical requirements. So, what would be the best choice? Hard-coding these Business Rules in Business Processes (it just sounds so wrong) or embedding a Business Rule Management System (with a Rules Engine) next to a Business Process Management?

My guess is that a Rule Engine is not the best choice for this. There are sometimes more than one possibilities and scenarios written down in each Business Rule and the common "if-then" statement does not apply in the most cases. 
So i found out that in most cases there is this "if-then" statement (literature etc.), but then the SBVR from the OMG comes in (Semantics of Business Vocabulary and Business Rules). It confuses me because there it isn't required to formulate rules with "if-then" et cetera.

I assume that these rules are not specifically meant to be built in a rules engine, but rather kept an eye on during the implementation of the software and after this process. Yet i think that these Business Rules might change. Wouldn't it be naive to hard-code them in Business Processes?

If there's anyone with a hint, i'd be very thankful.

BR

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you just need to choose the right tool for the job. You should take a look at the Drools and JBPM projects. Where the main goal is to make the rule engine to coexist with the process engine. So for some of those "Rules" you can create a business process to take care of it and for another one you can just write a proper business rule. And the third option is to mix both worlds.

Comment: thanks for your answer! i think that we can handle the business rules just as requirements, because they are only about 90 or so. A Business Rule Management tool with a Rule Engine would be over the top i guess.

Comment: Well it really depends on how often those rules changes and who are responsible for them. Business Processes and Business rules have the great advantage of being self documented and easy to understand to non IT people